# MonthCalendar to scroll to a different date when button is pressed

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a winforms with a MonthCalendar control and a button. The button has the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        myMonthCalendar.SelectionRange.Start = Convert.ToDateTime("01 jan 2012")
End Sub
```

What I was hoping would happen is that when I hit the button the calendar changes to the month of Jan 2012. When I hit the button no error occurs but it is still on the current month.

[image]

How do I get it to change to Jan 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This displays January 2012 on the button click and selects the 1st only:

```
myMonthCalendar.SetDate(Convert.ToDateTime("01 jan 2012"))
```

you can also use `SetSelectionRange` like phadaphunk mentioned, but note if you don't pass the same date for both parameters, multiple dates will be selected in the calendar up to the `MaxSelectionCount`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [SetSelectionRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.forms.monthcalendar.setselectionrange.aspx) method.

```
 myMonthCalendar.SetSelectionRange(StartDate, EndDate)
```

Selection range is used to play with the selection or to get it's range. (Start and End) the **SetSelectionRange()** is used to set it.